# YII2 - Rendering a view dynamically with parameters

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-model

I'm trying to create a system were I can define in admin, dynamic sidebars.  There are a few things I will have in the sidebar and one is to render a view.  Doing it without parameters and simple parameters, so like this

```
<?php 
  $view_filename = $component->view_filename // something like "my_sidebar.php";
  $param1 = $component->param1 // Something like "2"
          
  echo $this->render("/widgets/$view_filename", ['type' => $param1]); 
?>
```

is easy, but I'm having issues passing a model because I can't doing something like

```
<?php 
  $view_filename = $component->view_filename // something like "my_model_sidebar.php";
  $param1 = $component->param1 // Something like "$model"
          
  echo $this->render("/widgets/$view_filename", ['model' => $param1]); 
?>
```

Is it possible to do what I require?  I'm guessing this is stupidly easy but I just don't get it!

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to pass model? Yii doesn't care about what parameters you are passing into the view so passing `['model' => $param1]` works pretty much same as passing `['type' => $param1]`. The issue is somewhere else, but there is not enough info in your question to say where exactly.

Comment: You have to use common variable name or define variable names dynamically as well for view.